# How to add a specific script to the head section of Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I want to add different Google Analytics scripts (I prefer not using any plugin), for each blog in my multisite network and all blogs using different sub domains and with **one** theme.
let say I have

```
one.example.com 
two.example.com 
three.example.com
```

Right now to apply all Google Analytics script to all sub domains I wrote the script inside header.php main theme (I know this is not a good practice) so now I want to add Google analytics script using child theme in the functions.php

what is the best approach to do this? using `require_once` or write it inside child's functions.php or anything else?

I use this right now inside the main theme's header.php

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'one.example.com'){ ?>

<script>
// GA script for one.example.com
</script>

<?php }elseif ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'two.example.com'){ ?>

<script>
//GA script for two.example.com
</script>

<?php } ?>
```